# Is there a way to make a variable in C only accessible to the file in which it was declared?

Tags: c, scope

Is there a way to make a variable in C only accessible to the file in which it was declared?

I am asking this because I remember reading somewhere that it's possible to do that, but I really can't remember how to do that. Is it possible, or am I just imagining?

Comment: I thought it was the `static` keyword, but doesn't `static` make the variable stay in memory until the program finishes execution? That's confusing me now...

Comment: `static` is (unfortunately) used for many unrelated things in C. For block variables, it gives the variable static storage duration. For global variables (which already have static storage duration), it controls visibility. It's even more overloaded in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `static` keyword will give the global variable internal linkage, meaning that the **name** will not be visible to other translation units. However, note that this differs from what you asked for in that:

- The name could still be accessed from other **files** included in the same translation unit (files included via the `#include` directive).
- The variable can still be accessed by other translation units (modules) in your program if they can obtain its address, for example if there's a function in the same translation unit as your `static` variable which returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a static global.

```
static int foo;
int incrementfoo()
{
    return ++foo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

static is the word you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `static` keyword does that; by contrast, the `extern` keyword can let you import other variables from other files.